# How to navigate through an array of urls as list of links and with previous/next links?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of urls that I want to display one by one in an iframe. The user will navigate to each URL by clicking a link in a list of the URLs or by clicking the previous/next links. What is the best way to do this? Working code snippets would be very very appreciated.

I'm posting as few details as possible below for best clarity.

```
var urls = [{"name":"ebay","url":"http://ebay.com"},
{"name":"amazon","url":"http://amazon.com"},
{"name":"msn","url":"http://msn.com"},
{"name":"yahoo","url":"http://yahoo.com"},
{"name":"wikipedia","url":"http://wikipedia.org"}];
```

List of links (alternate way to navigate instead of prev/next links below)

```
<ol id="list">
  <li><a href="" target="myframe">ebay</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="myframe">amazon</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="myframe">msn</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="myframe">yahoo</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="myframe">wikipedia</a></li>
</ol>

currently viewing: <span id="current"></span>

prev: <a href="" target="myframe"></a> | next: <a href="" target="myframe"></a>

//all the links will open inside this iframe using target="myframe"
<iframe src="" name="myframe" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your next and previous links ids

```
prev: <a href="" id="prev" target="myframe"></a> | next: <a id="next" href="" target="myframe"></a>
```

Then some basic script should wire this up

```
var currentIndex = 0;
function next(){
    if (currentIndex != Urls.length - 1)
        load(urls[++currentIndex].url);
}

function previous(){
    if (currentIndex != 0)
        load(urls[--currentIndex].url);
}

function() load(url){
    $("#myframe").attr("src", url);
}

$(function() {
    $("#prev").click(function() { previous(); });
    $("#next").click(function() { next(); });
});
```

To handle the explicit links, I'd use data attributes to store the url, and use the same load function:

```
<ol id="list">
  <li><a href="#" data-url="www.ebay.com" >ebay</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-url="www.amazon.com" >amazon</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-url="..." >msn</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-url="..." >yahoo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-url="..." >wikipedia</a></li>
</ol>
```

Then inside that jQuery document load function, something like:

```
$("#list a").click(function() { load($(this).data("url")); });
```

So the whole thing would look like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#prev").click(function() { previous(); });
    $("#next").click(function() { next(); });
    $("#list a").click(function() { load($(this).data("url")); });
});
```

Comment: @ofko - I made a few edits and got your code working  http://jsbin.com/atenaq/5/edit